# error during pip update

Tags: pip, cygwin

I am using pip in a cygwin environment under Win10.

```
$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from c:\python36\lib\site-packages (python 3.6)
```

I had coded a bash function `molt` to do python package maintenance in the past

```
molt () {
  local i
  for i in $(pip list | cut -d' ' -f1)
  do
    case $i in
      pip|pywin32)
        continue
      ;;
      *)
        pip install -qU $i
      ;;
    esac
  done
}
```

It worked until last week.

```
$ molt
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\cygwin64\tmp\pip-build-lbe5xcu8\Package\

Usage:
pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --------------
```

I suspect pip must have changed but couldn't figure out what change broke the code. Please help.

Comment: The `pip` you are using is NOT the cywin one. May be you have an interference between two versions of python.

Comment: @matzeri I am using the pip from Python distribution (also not a cygwin one). In other words, all the Python stuff is not from the cygwin distribution but I am using Python in cygwin as python/pip/etc. are in the environment path. So there's only one version of python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that `pip list` returns

```
Package        Version
-------------- -------
pip            9.0.1
setuptools     38.5.2
```

which leads `pip install -qU Package --------------` according to the `molt` function, causing the error. The culprit is the new `pip list` output format (I forgot that I have changed the default `legacy` to `columns` a while ago). Restoring the default format option fixes the error, i.e.,

```
pip list --format=legacy
```